# iOS - Draw Within an Irregular Area

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing

I'm ok with iOS drawing.  I've had no problem drawing circles, lines, etc onto a view.   In my latest project I would like to restrict my drawing to an irregular area on my view.  Basically I have a paper doll outline (jpg) of a person.  I want to be able to draw within that outline but have drawing stop when I reach the border.   I'm honestly not really sure what my approach can be to accomplish this.  Do I have to do hit testing to see if I'm within this irregular region?   I don't think that is realistic if I start with a JPG.  Do I need to use a "special" color outside my region and test for that color under my brush?   I'm worried that won't be accurate as I'm using a big fat fuzzy brush to draw.

Is it possible to restrict drawing within an irregular boundary?

Comment: How is your irregular area defined? Does the "doll" have an outline?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible!

If you are drawing with CoreGraphics (Quartz), you could use a [clipping path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF126), or a [bitmap mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101).

If you are using CoreAnimation, then try a [mask layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/LayerVisProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006074-SW21).

(It sounds like a bitmap mask is what you want, since you're talking about using an arbitrary JPEG image.)

Comment: @simusid please mark the answer as correct, and be gentle enough to leave an upvote if it helped you.